# Ratchet умирает при закрытии консоли

Tags: php, ratchet, daemon

Здравствуйте. Поднял сервер на ratchet, всё как в документации. Локально под windows работает нормально. Перенес на VDS с CentOS, управление через ISPmanager. Запускаю скрипт через консоль, все работает, но стоит окно с консолью закрыть, ratchet перестает работать. При обращении к скрипту через браузер, через определенное время появляется ошибка 504 gateway timeout. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в конец команды запуска `&`

Comment: Попробовал. Консоль выдает какое-то число (я так полагаю, ИД процесса),но клиент сервер не видит.

Comment: попробуйте через `nohup (команда) &`

Comment: Спасибо. Вроде помогло.